# Invalid argument in IE11 when using computed value for angular translate

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-translate

The advice when using angular translate is to [prefer the directive over the filter](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Getting-Started#using-translate-directive). Now at some places I need to construct the translation keys dynamically, e.g.

```
<span translate>{{'Prefix' + vm.foo}}</span>
```

This works in Chrome and Firefox, but produces an "invalid argument" somewhere deep in the angular sources in IE. Here is a stack trace of one such error:

```
Error: Invalid argument.
   at interpolateFnWatchAction (http://localhost:53559/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8020:17)
   at interpolateFnWatcher (http://localhost:53559/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10177:17)
   at watchGroupAction (http://localhost:53559/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13915:13)
   at Scope.prototype.$digest (http://localhost:53559/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14243:23)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:53559/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14506:13)
   at done (http://localhost:53559/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9659:36)
   at completeRequest (http://localhost:53559/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9849:7)
   at requestLoaded (http://localhost:53559/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9790:9) undefined
```

Interestingly, the error comes from angular itself, not from angular translate.

Of course, the workaround is to use

```
<span>{{'Prefix' + vm.foo | translate}}</span>
```

But my question is: Is that a bug, or expected behavior? If so, why is it browser-specific?

EDIT

We use angular v1.3.14 and angular-translate v2.6.1.

Comment: Do you have some more details on the versions you're using on angular-translate and AngularJS?

Comment: @Yosh I added the versions to the question.

Comment: I guess, that it might be related to this issue here: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/925

Comment: @Yosh Indeed! I was unable to find that one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @Yosh in a comment, this problem is a known bug, see https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/925 .

The workaround is to use the translate filter instead of the directive.